# How to scale efficiently geo restriction data from MySQL data storage

Tags: mysql, database, scalability

I have the following tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `media_scores` (
  `media_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sorting_score` float unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `date_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`media_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `media_restrict` (
  `media_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `restrict_type` enum('exclude','include') NOT NULL,
  `country_code` char(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`media_id`,`restrict_type`,`countryCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Table media_scores has 1.8M records.
Table media_restrict has equal or more records.

Here are some sample data inside:
media_scores

```
+----------+---------------+-------------+--------------+
| media_id | sorting_score | date_added  | date_updated |
+----------+---------------+-------------+--------------+
|        1 |           25  | 2014-11-05  | 0000-00-00   |
|       2  |           16  | 2014-11-05  | 0000-00-00   |
|       3  |           33  | 2014-11-05  | 0000-00-00   |
|       4  |           11  | 2014-11-04  | 0000-00-00   |
+----------+---------------+-------------+--------------+
```

media_restrict

```
+----------+---------------+--------------+
| media_id | restrict_type | country_code |
+----------+---------------+--------------+
|        1 | exclude       | US           |
|        1 | exclude       | UK           |
|        2 | include       | US           |
|        2 | include       | CA           |
|        3 | include       | CN           |
+----------+---------------+--------------+
```

I am running the following query:

```
SELECT ms.*
FROM media_scores as ms
LEFT OUTER JOIN media_restrict AS mr
ON ms.media_id = mr.media_id and mr.restrict_type = 'exclude' and mr.country_code = 'CA'
LEFT OUTER JOIN media_restrict AS mr2
ON ms.media_id = mr2.media_id AND mr2.restrict_type = 'include' AND mr2.country_code = 'CA'
LEFT OUTER JOIN media_restrict AS mr3
ON ms.media_id = mr3.media_id AND mr3.restrict_type = 'include' AND mr3.country_code != 'CA'
WHERE mr.media_id IS NULL AND
(CASE mr2.media_id WHEN ms.media_id THEN NULL ELSE mr3.media_id END) IS NULL;
```

to achieve this:

```
+----------+---------------+------------+--------------+
| media_id | sorting_score | date_added | date_updated |
+----------+---------------+------------+--------------+
|        1 |            25 | 2014-11-05 | 0000-00-00   |
|        2 |            16 | 2014-11-05 | 0000-00-00   |
|       4  |            11 | 2014-11-04 | 0000-00-00   |
+----------+---------------+------------+--------------+
```

On small subset - the query runs fine.
On 1.8M Im having issues in scalability.

What I basically want to achieve in the end is to have the items inside media_scores to show to countries that is allowed only.

I am very flexible in terms of infrastructure so MySQL may not be the solution but it is all I can wrap my head around with.

The data set will grow as I fill up with more data and more countries restrictions.

How can I restrict my data according to countries efficiently in the larger scale. How does any given services check for content restrictions (like Youtube that cannot display content depending on countries).

There are two things that needs to be considered: speed and accuracy.
The current benchmark is about 13seconds and if I load this as a data set and then I have to manipulate it - its beyond too long. Accuracy means I need to ensure I get the proper result that I need. Currently the query mentioned is correct.

Note: data are updated frequently but not to the minute (i would say every hour or so maybe more) - therefore Vertica can offer large data set to be query efficiently but since Vertica doesn't support updates or deletion nicely - it rules that out.

Answer (score 1):

There's a little ambiguity in your question - for any given media_id, could you have included *and* excluded countries? It seems that if you include countries, the natural assumption would be all other countries are excluded and vice versa (if you exclude countries, all others would be included) - is that true? If so, then for a given media_id, you'd only have either include or exclude but not both.

And if I'm interpreting your query correctly, that'd simplify it by allowing you to not worry about this part:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN media_restrict AS mr3
ON ms.media_id = mr3.media_id AND mr3.restrict_type = 'include' AND mr3.country_code != 'CA'
WHERE mr.media_id IS NULL AND
(CASE mr2.media_id WHEN ms.media_id THEN NULL ELSE mr3.media_id END) IS NULL;
```

There are other big improvements you can make, but they depend on your answer to my question above so I'll let you answer that first.

Comment: That is correct - you can only be included or excluded not both for a given media_id. HOWEVER I need the last part for "global" media_id. If you look at the expected result: media_id 4 needs to show up - which is neither included or excluded, because its not restricted to any country.